# Have I correctly set out what would happen in my boot sector/loader?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader

I'm trying to make a simple boot loader to setup for my kernel in C to take over, and I'm not sure how to do that. I've laid out using comments what I think I need to do to prepare for this.

test.asm:

```
;test.asm

;initialization type stuff
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]

;initialize anything I need to

;maybe move to 64-bit protected mode
;load kernel
;call kmain

;padding & magic number (end)
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

kernel.c:

```
//kernel.c

//main entry point for kernel
int kmain(void)
{
    //video memory
    char *vidptr = (char*)0xb8000;
    vidptr[0] = 'X';
    while(1) {}
    return 0; //might create an error because it is unreachable
}
```

I'd appreciate help in correcting the process I'm trying to do. Help with actually getting my boot loader to call the kernel would be great as well.

Comment: You don’t actually need a bootloader, but if you want one, do what you want in it then jump to the start address of the kernel. The start of the kernel should be placed at a specific memory address so you can jump to it, check the documentation for your linker and how to place the kernel at a specific memory address. What MCU are you using?

Comment: The proccess of actually calling the kernel is easiest done via asm through a jump or just setting the PC to the start address of the kernel.

Comment: Freestanding systems don't use `int main (void)`, who are you gonna return to? Also one never uses `char` for raw binary manipulations since it might be signed, use `uint8_t` instead. And to access physical addresses you need to use `volatile uint8_t*`. These are very basic things...

Comment: I would assume I'd be returning to where the line of execution came from, the assembly script.

Comment: @Fredrik: jumps *are* how you set PC (specifically IP/EIP/RIP on x86).  IDK why you said "or".  Maybe you're thinking of 32-bit ARM where PC is one of the 16 architectural registers, so you can jump with a `mov` to PC?  Notice that this question is tagged [tag:x86], and from context we can infer that it's a PC-compatible system booting in legacy BIOS mode.  (512-byte boot sector ending with `0xaa55`, containing machine code that will run in 16-bit real mode.)

Comment: But anyway, `call kmain` is not pseudocode, that's a literal x86 `call` instruction.  (Except it won't work unless you link the bootloader and the kernel together into one binary, and that's not recommended.)

Comment: I've seen somewhere saying you don't have to link everything into a single file. Can I not call a function from a different file in the same location?

Comment: You need to spend some time at https://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page - There are tutorials covering everything you are asking about.

Comment: @liaquore: Don't think of it as a function call into the kernel, think of it as the bootloader *jumping* to the kernel (and the kernel only cares about itself, not the bootloader's memory).  So the bootloader loads some sectors into memory at an address it chooses, then jumps *to that address* (or to a point within that region).  You use a linker script to make sure the entry for your kernel is at the first byte.  (A fancier kernel like Linux would have some hand-written asm for the actual entry point from the bootloader, doing some decompression and stuff before calling a C function.)